# Value Error: Cannot query "post": Must be "UserProfile" instance

Tags: python, django

I am getting the `Value Error: Cannot query "post": Must be "UserProfile" instance` when I make a get request to call `PostListView.as_view()`.
Here is my model.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
    

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py :

```
class PostListView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class    = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
   
    def get_queryset(self):
        """Returns only the object related to current user"""
        user = self.request.user
        return Post.objects.filter(user=user)
```

Also, I want a Foreign key relationship exists between User and Post on Model-level, not on the Database level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user is UserProfile instance but request.user is a User instance

change this line like that to refernece to userprofile

```
user = self.request.user.userprofile
```

Comment: What about this - Also, I want a Foreign key relationship exists between User and Post on Model-level, not on the Database level.

Comment: I think dont need that. You can access to user with UserProfile or you can change FK from UserProfile to User and access User profile through User